# How can I arrange floats across rather than down a page?

Tags: floats

I have a document with about 90 floats that are a mixture of single and double-column width. It seems that the double-column floats interfere with the placement of the single-column ones, and therefore most right columns come out empty. Is it possible to have floats appear across rather than down each page? The sketch below shows the desired and the actual placement of floats.

[image: Desired and actual placement of floats]

Comment: You could put 1 + 2 inside one float environment.

Comment: If you don't need the floating, but them besides each other in minipages and use \captionof from caption package

Comment: if you know you want them in a continuous list then they should not be floating at all.

Comment: You could also pair 1 & 2 in one float, and 4 & 5 in another.  You can have more than one \caption in a float, but each should be in different minipage.  I would put them all in one [p] float.

Comment: If the floats are figures, would the `subfig` package help?

Comment: The floats were lstlisting elements. I followed the advice of @DavidCarlisle and abandoned the idea of floating them.